# How to group by two input values in columns and set them in a row

Tags: python

Current input:

```
reg1 test1 f day1
reg1 test2 p day1
reg1 test3 p day2
reg1 test2 p day2
reg1 test2 p day3
reg1 test4 f day3
```

Desired output:

```
reg   test  day1 day2 day3
reg1  test1   f   -    -
reg1  test2   p   p    p
reg1  test3   -   p    -
reg1  test4   -   -    f
```

How can I get the desired output from the current input? I want to use only the built-in features of python as I cannot download libraries like pandas, tabulate, etc.

Comment: I think you're looking for some kind of pivot? Are you using any libraries for data analysis like numpy or similar?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How are you getting your inputs? More information is needed to answer this question.

Comment: chris, I am not using any library. I cannot install any new libraries because of restricted access to downloads. I looking for a simpler way to do this.

Comment: @StevenSummers I get this as a part of input from a text file, which infact is an output of one other perl script.

Comment: What are you limitations? Please edit your question with more details.

Comment: @StevenSummers done! :)

Answer (score 0):

Say your data is in `stuff.csv`. Start by loading it

```
tups = [l.strip().split(' ') for l in open('stuff.csv') if l.strip()]
>>> tups
[['reg1', 'test1', 'f', 'day1'],
 ['reg1', 'test2', 'p', 'day1'],
 ['reg1', 'test3', 'p', 'day2'],
 ['reg1', 'test2', 'p', 'day2'],
 ['reg1', 'test2', 'p', 'day3'],
 ['reg1', 'test4', 'f', 'day3']]
```

Now find all possible days

```
days = sorted(set(tup[3] for tup in tups))
>>> days
{'day1', 'day2', 'day3'}
```

Now calculate all entries for regs and tests

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
for tup in tups:
    d[(tup[0], tup[1])][tup[3]] = tup[2]
>>> d
defaultdict(dict,
            {('reg1', 'test1'): {'day1': 'f'},
             ('reg1', 'test2'): {'day1': 'p', 'day2': 'p', 'day3': 'p'},
             ('reg1', 'test3'): {'day2': 'p'},
             ('reg1', 'test4'): {'day3': 'f'}})
```

Finally, calculate a list of the outputs:

```
out = []
for e in d:
    out.append(
        list(e) + [d[e][day] if day in d[e] else '-' for day in days])
>>> out
[['reg1', 'test2', 'p', 'p', 'p'],
 ['reg1', 'test4', '-', 'f', '-'],
 ['reg1', 'test1', '-', '-', 'f'],
 ['reg1', 'test3', 'p', '-', '-']]
```

Outputting this in a CSV should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a simple task of loading and unloading nested dictionaries. I used sys.stdin for example purposes, your code would likely come from a open() so you could toss the import of sys:

```
import sys

dictionary = {}

days = set()

for line in sys.stdin:
    reg, test, letter, day = line.rstrip().split(' ')

    if reg not in dictionary:
        dictionary[reg] = dict()

    if test not in dictionary[reg]:
        dictionary[reg][test] = dict()

    if day not in dictionary[reg][test]:
        dictionary[reg][test][day] = dict()

    dictionary[reg][test][day] = letter

    days.add(day)

days = sorted(list(days))

print("reg", "test#", *days, sep="\t")

for reg in sorted(dictionary):
    reg_dict = dictionary[reg]

    for test in sorted(reg_dict):
        test_dict = reg_dict[test]

        letters = [test_dict[day] if day in test_dict else "-" for day in days]

        print(reg, test, *letters, sep="\t")
```

(Change the split character to match your actual input.) Not perfect but basically works:

```
reg     test#   day1    day2    day3
reg1    test1   f       -       -
reg1    test2   p       p       p
reg1    test3   -       p       -
reg1    test4   -       -       f
```